# How to consume .NET Core FileContentResult in an httpClient test method

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, integration-testing

I have a .NET Core 2.2 API Controller method that returns a FileContentResult like so:

```
  [HttpGet]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
  {
    return File(_service.GetCsvFile(), "text/csv", "results.csv");
  }
```

Also, I have an integration test that uses a WebHostFixture and httpClient to get the results. However, the content is always empty, whatever method I try. While there is a file with content being returned:

```
  var response = await WebHost.Client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);

  var result = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

Also, when I do the following, no content is being read:

```
  var response = await WebHost.Client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
```

All other integration tests using this WebHostFixture run successful, so it seems this is the only endpoint that is not returning its data properly in my test environment. When I call the endpoint using [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info), a CSV file with content is being returned properly.

Also, in Postman, besides receiving the binary data in the body, the following headers are returned:

[image]

However, in my test method, after calling the GetAsync method, the
`response.Content.Headers.ContentType` is `"text/csv"`, but the             `response.Content.Headers.ContentLength` is 0.

What am I doing wrong and why is there no binary data being returned here?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the test and setting a breakpoint?

Comment: Of course, in the controller method a proper FileContentResult is being returned with data, in the test the result is an empty byte[].

Comment: You said it works in PostMan, but I am wondering if you can see the file content when you are debugging the test itself, before the controller method returns. I ask because the file path `"result.csv"` may be relative to the test project.

Comment: the 3rd parameter to File is a filename not a path. The controller works fine, a csv file is returned. In postman, the response headers also have a proper value for Content-Length, in the integration test response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = 0 but response.Content.Headers.ContentType = "text/csv"

Comment: use the `await` before the reading content. like: `var result = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();`

Comment: ofcourse that was meant to be await, but still no response data...

Comment: Did you check whether you response has a successful status code in HttpResponseMessage?

Comment: Can you edit and post how your WebHostFixture is?

Comment: Is your GetCsvFile async? Maybe since you are not awaiting anything in your controller but the controller is async. Maybe you were lucky in postman to get the body but when testing locally it's too fast so the body gets discarded because of no await. Just a guess.

Also check status code of the test, maybe it's simply a 404 or similar.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
byte[] BytesResult = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync("YourRequestUri").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score -2):

Convert it to string and compare the result. It works great with approval tests.
Example:

```
var result = fileresult as FileContentResult; 

byte[] buffer =  result.FileContents;

string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Answer (score -6):

When reading a file you need to use `GetStreamAsync`

Example:

```
using (var csvStream = await WebHost.Client.GetStreamAsync(url))
{
    // Do something with stream contents.
}
```